# Ubuntu Eclipse Jboss Tools

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, wildfly

I am trying to install jboss tools in eclipse mars in order to create a WildFly server under Ubuntu. Unfortunately, after installing from the market, the adapter list still does not contain jboss entries.

I have modified my *eclipse.ini* to add *-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java* but problem persits.

Here is the output of my javac -version :

> ~/$ javac -version
>
> javac 1.8.0_74

Comment: What do you mean by *...the adapter list still does not contain JBoss entries*?

Comment: When I try to add a new server, I don't see any jboss server adapters

Comment: Did you restart your Eclipse after installing it?

Comment: Yes I have restarted several times with no success. I also installed openjdk-8 and tried running eclipse with it - still no luck

Comment: Humm... Well, what I advise you is to remove the installation you've made from the Marketplace and do it using [JBoss Tools update site](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/mars/4.3.0.Final.html#update_site).

Comment: Does the log in workspace/.metadata/.log tells you anything about some missing constraint? It can be that the -vm setting is not passed correctly. If "java -version" -not javac- returns java 8, then you can try to remove the -vm setting and try again.

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem by uninstalling all java versions below JDK8 and reinstalling eclipse using the new eclipse installer. For some reason, it does matter what version you select during installation (probably updates more than just the eclipse.ini)